# How can I take a percentage-wise subset of a data frame?

Tags: r

Consider the following code:

```
baseball <- read.csv("c:\\Users\\Jim\\Downloads\\MLB2008.csv", header = T)  
baseball[1:70,]
```

This code will print out the first 70 rows of the data frame named 'baseball'.

- I'd like to print out the first 70% of the rows of the data frame named 'baseball'.
- And then I'd like to print out the last 30% of the rows of the data frame named 'baseball'.

How can I do this?

Comment: Perhaps `baseball[seq(round(nrow(baseball)*70)/100)),]`

Comment: If you want to do this directly from the file, you could find the number of rows in the file with `length(count.fields(file))` then use `skip` and `nrow` in `read.csv()` to create a list of two

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
cutoff = round(0.7*nrow(baseball))

baseball[1:cutoff,]
baseball[-(1:cutoff),]
```

Comment: Interesting. So that minus operator says `Take the bottom`?

Comment: The minus operator in a row index says: exclude those rows.

Answer (score 3):

Using `head` and `tail`.

```
head(baseball, round(nrow(baseball)*0.7))
tail(baseball, round(nrow(baseball)*0.3))
```